# getFragmentManager().findFragmentById возвращает NULL

Tags: java, android, null

Пытаюсь изменить поля фрагмента динамически, но постоянно `getFragmentManager().findFragmentById` возвращает `NULL`. Если использовать статический фрагмент, то работает без проблем. Не могу понять в чем проблема, перепробовал массу вариантов.

```
public class DetailActivity extends Activity{

    FilmList mFilmList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detail);

        mFilmList = (FilmList)getIntent().getParcelableExtra("FilmList");
        int position = getIntent().getIntExtra("position", 0);

        Fragment  fragment;
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction;
        fragment = new ViewFragment();
        fragmentTransaction = this.getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        HashMap<String, Object> map = mFilmList.getList().get(position);
        fragment = getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frame);
        ((TextView) fragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.ftext1))
                .setText((String) map.get(FilmModel.sNAME));
        /*
        ((TextView) fragment1.getView().findViewById(R.id.ftext2))
                .setText((String)map.get(FilmModel.sTIME));
        ((TextView) fragment1.getView().findViewById(R.id.ftext3))
                .setText((String)map.get(FilmModel.sDESC));*/
    }

}

    public class ViewFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_fragment, null);
        setRetainInstance(true);
        return view;

    }
}
```

**XML: Activity_detail**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="ua.test.wantedy.test.ViewFragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    tools:layout="@layout/view_fragment">
</fragment>
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:layout="@layout/view_fragment"
    android:layout_weight="1">
</FrameLayout>
```

**XML: view_fragment**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ftext1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is Title"
    android:textSize="35sp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ftext2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is Time" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/ftext3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="This is Description"
    android:textSize="25sp" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/fimage"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:contentDescription="Img" />
```

Единственная мысль, что вероятно в момент обращения к фрагменту он еще не создан? Хотя вроде как должен был..

Comment: Добавлять фрагмент в разметку - плохая идея. Попробуйте его оттуда убрать и добавлять только в коде.

Comment: если динамически добавить фрагмент и тут же вызвать его View - вылетает `NullPointerExeption`, так как он еще не успевает обработаться. Нужно вызывать его позже (на клике, например), либо добавлять связку `try{}catch{}`, которая правда тоже не всегда корректно работает.

Comment: @AbrogPetrovich Пожалуйста, опубликуйте ваш комментарий в виде ответа.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если динамически добавить фрагмент и тут же вызвать его `View` - вылетает `NullPointerExeption`, так как он еще не успевает обработаться. Нужно вызывать его позже (на клике, например), либо добавлять связку `try{}catch{}`, которая правда тоже не всегда корректно работает.
В вашем случае можно передавать текст во фрагмент в момент его создания, через

```
public static MyFragment newInstance(String txt) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putInt("text", txt);
    MyFragment fragment = new MyFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}
```

и в `onCreateView()` вызывать текст через `getArguments().getString("text")`

в Активити новый фрагмент добавляется так: `MyFragment.newInstance(myText);` вместо `new MyFragment`

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я так и предполагал. Фрагмент в разметке, потому что я пробовал оба варианта и статика в таком случае корректно работает, а вот динамика вылетает. Теперь разобрался.